# Concatenating string inside javascript object definition

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, object

I'm trying to put together a regex router that includes an arbitrary number of slugs and key-values.

I'm doing this by creating an object of patterns and their respective modules and will then match the regex to the module.

But JavaScript throws an error when I use the "+" operator to concatenate strings inside of the object definition.

```
// URI PATTERNS
var SLUG ='\/[a-z|A-Z|0-9|-]+)([\/]{0,1})?';
var KEYS ='\/?(\?.*)?$/';

// ROUTES 
var routes = {

    '\/public\/images'  +   KEYS                : 'images', /* <-- ERROR: '+' Unexpected token */
    '\/public\/other'   +   SLUG    +   KEYS    : 'something-else',

};
```

Why is this error being thrown and how can I concatenate these values outside of storing them in separate variables?

Comment: Object must have a **property name** and a value assigned to it. You can access the value in a object by its property. That is what you are missing

Comment: the property names are supposed to be the concatenated strings and the values would be the modules (images, etc)

Comment: Oh ya .. I overlooked it. You just need to use the `[ ]` to add property values then . Like just have a routes plain object like `routes= {}` then you can do `routes[ your concatenation logic] = 'images';`

Comment: ah! yes. perfect. I guess I was trying to do it all in the declaration. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// URI PATTERNS
var SLUG = '\/[a-z|A-Z|0-9|-]+)([\/]{0,1})?';
var KEYS = '\/?(\?.*)?$/';

// ROUTES 
var routes = {};

function addRoute(keyParts, value){
  routes[keyParts.join('')] = value;
}

addRoute(['\/public\/images', KEYS], 'images');
addRoute(['\/public\/other', SLUG, KEYS], 'something-else');

console.log(routes);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var SLUG ='\/[a-z|A-Z|0-9|-]+)([\/]{0,1})?';
var KEYS ='\/?(\?.*)?$/';

function obj(){
    obj=new Object();
    this.add=function(key,value){
        obj[key]=value;
    }
    this.obj=obj
}

routes=new obj();
routes.add(['\/public\/images'+ KEYS], 'images');
routes.add(['\/public\/other' + SLUG + KEYS],'something-else');

console.log(routes.obj);
```

Comment: What is the reason for doing `""+key+""`? Why are you creating a new object inside the constructor when you could just say `this.add = function(key, value) { this[key] = value; }`?

Answer (score 0):

Use computed property names:

```
var routes = {
  [`\/public\/images${KEYS}`]: 'images',
```

The above also uses ES6 template literals.